# How to upload images to app store?

Tags: app-store

I'm struggling to get images uploaded to iTunes Connect. I am on the below screen in Safari, but the "Choose file" option is disabled.

[image: App store media manager]

I have tried to drag and drop images into it, but it never does anything.

If I uncheck the ones currently checked; they I can drag and drop images into; but never the very first items.

Can someone assist how I upload the images?

Comment: You selected 5.5 inch Display So make sure your Screenshot size is 1242x2208

Comment: thats great well you can appreciate my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38953514/1308632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was indicated above;

> You selected 5.5 inch Display So make sure your Screenshot size is
>   1242x2208

Further, I noticed that an extra localisation was created that I didn't need; deleting this also helped solved the problem.