# Creating the Next App Version submit for review show an error

Tags: submit, app-store-connect

I want to creating the Next App Version in iTunes Connect but , after upload and click on "submit for review" I receive this error message:
[image]

Same as you see apple show only one red bag on localized and no let to submit for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error message because ITC has recently changed rules in uploading screenshots.

As per that rules :

- You must submit 5.5 inch (1242x2208) size screenshot for iPhone & 12.9 inch (2732x2048) size screenshot for iPad
- You can upload other sizes of screenshots from media manager but only if your application has localization feature & you wanting to show other language screenshots. You have to add that language in that case

**Note:**

- If your application not contains localization feature than just keep 5.5 & 12.9 inch screenshots & remove other size screenshots & than try to submit it.

Hope it will guide you.